# removeChild giving error #2025

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I have an issue with the removeChild function for the healthBar of my enemies. When they are destroyed, I remove their hp bar too. However, I get the error #2025: DisplayObject must be child of the caller. The strange part is that it works and the hpBar is removed. I tried adding a breakpoint when the remove child function is called but I never receive the error this way.

```
if(level.enemies[enemyNum].healthBar != null){
    level.levelObjects.removeChild(level.enemies[enemyNum].healthBar);
}
```

This is the code that removes that healthBar and the error I get is for this line.

Thanks for the help. Let me know if you need more code or have any questions.

Comment: Need a Bigger snippet, something that involves when enemies dies and when they are visually removed. Given your new bug, it seems like you remove enemies from list and thus get an incorrect counter on the array... However, since that is a new bug you should open a new question and if your original question is solved accept mgraphs answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
if(level.levelObjects.contains(level.enemies[enemyNum].healthBar)){
    level.levelObjects.removeChild(level.enemies[enemyNum].healthBar);
}
```

Comment: Those both give me an error since the healthBar object is child of the levelObjects. levelObjects is basically a sprite in my level and I add the childs in this sprite. It currently works the way it's done and the healthBar is removed but I get the error anyway.

Comment: I tried that earlier and it seems to be working since I don't get this error anymore. However, I get the weirdest bug that removes a random enemy(not the one destroyed) sprite but leaves this enemy hpBar and events so I see a hpBar, without the enemy sprite, that moves and shoot bullets. I don't know if this is related to the hpBar removal but it only happens when I have the contains() method.